# Creating multiple slider in one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, coda-slider

I have been struggling on this for one day..

I need to make a webpage that contains 6 different box, with different content.
And i want every of them has coda slider ability, in this case i am using coda slider from this website..

```
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/
```

i have created different div, and add additional .js file with the new div, but still, the multiple box sliding function are conflicted. I hope anyone may give his/her time to look at this problem.. thanks before..

Answer (score 1):

The code as-is on the site is hardcoded to use "slider" id for the div of the slider, you'd have to change it accept others id, and make sure the ids of all your elements are unique.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/amirshim/AFjX5/

Comment: thank you very much Amir, i tried the link you give,
i have another blog with <div id="bslider">, and i have added
$(document).ready(function() {
    createSlider($('#slider'));
    createSlider($('#bslider'));
});
but the #bslider block won't work, and also the slider, have a very nice sliding effect that i want to use, but with the code you modified, the sliding effect wont work, any suggestion ?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing what you have.